# Multiple Emotion Caches

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, emotion

Is it possible to:

- Create multiple emotions caches for different themes
- Generate the statically generated pages and documents only once
- Decide for each request which emotion chache to append depending on a cookie

I think this is possible but I'm not sure about the last one. If it is how to do it?

Comment: There is a dedicated Discussion to this topic now: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/36502